# NoSuchElementException: Using webdriver to get sequences from Uniprot

Tags: css, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to download protein sequences from Uniprot with the following code.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_location)

#get website 
driver.get('https://www.uniprot.org/uniprotkb/P19515/entry#sequences')

#stall to load webpage
time.sleep(5)

#scroll webpage
#driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")


#create instance of button and click
button = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Copy sequence")
button.click()
```

Running the previous block of code returns the following error

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Copy sequence"}
```

Additionally, here is the css layout
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AF19K.jpg)

I assume the problem is the button is either dynamic or hidden in some way that the webdriver cannot locate the button. I know there is a Uniport API and probably other more efficient ways to download protein sequences but for the sake of learning how can I modify my code and why isn't the button clickable?

Answer (score 0):

Link text only works if the locator has a hyperlink, so in this case it wont work since its a button which copies the the text into the clipboard and doesn't a `href` tag.

however you can modify your code to

```
button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.button.primary.tertiary")
```

and it will perform the click operation.

Answer (score 0):

`link_text` only works for `a` tags, not `button` tags. But if you use the [SeleniumBase framework on GitHub](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase), there's a special `TAG:contains("TEXT")` selector that you can use to click the button.

Here's a working script: (After installing `seleniumbase` using `pip install seleniumbase`, run the script with `python` or `pytest`)

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase

class RecorderTest(BaseCase):
    def test_recording(self):
        self.open("https://www.uniprot.org/uniprotkb/P19515/entry#sequences")
        self.click('button:contains("Copy sequence")')
        self.sleep(3)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from pytest import main
    main([__file__])
```

You can use the [SeleniumBase Recorder](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/help_docs/recorder_mode.md) to generate a script like that from manual browser actions. The last part with `if __name__ == "__main__":` lets you run the script with `python` instead of just `pytest`.